# Postgres index gets corrupted on drop tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a weird error with Postgres: whenever I `drop` my tables and recreate them again, I get this error:

```
Fatal: Error: can't insert into `accounts` table. error=pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "account_pkey"
```

To fix this I do:

```
reindexdb mydb
```

And it works, all the time. This bug is reproducible 100% of the time. 
What I am doing wrong? Why the indexes become corrupt ? Any suggestions on how to debug this issue?

I don't think it is relevant, but the accounts table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
        account_id                      SERIAL                  PRIMARY KEY,
        owner_id                        INT                     NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        last_balance                    NUMERIC                 DEFAULT 0,
        num_tx                          BIGINT                  DEFAULT 0,
        ts_created                      INT                     DEFAULT 0,
        block_created                   INT                     DEFAULT 0,
        deleted                         SMALLINT                DEFAULT 0,
        block_sd                        INT                     DEFAULT 0,
        address                         TEXT                    NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX account_addr_idx   ON      account                 USING   hash    ("address");
CREATE INDEX account_owner_idx  ON      account                 USING   btree   ("owner_id");
CREATE INDEX account_deleted_idx ON     account                 USING   btree   ("deleted");
```

I have tried dropping connections, or restarting postgres daemon, nothing works, except reindexing, but only after I get the actual error. Reindexing immediately after creating new tables doesn't avoid the error.

Comment: Have you actually checked your data for duplicates on `account_id`?

Comment: @KamilG. duplicates are impossible to occur, after `drop table` and recreation of the tables , since the database is empty

Comment: @KamilG.this problem happens on the first attempt to insert. And if there would be duplicates, the `reindexdb` command wouldn't fix it

Comment: I won't be able to reproduce it without data that's causing it. It works fine for me.

Comment: @KamilG. is there a way to list the content of the index in postgres? maybe I can use this to check if immediately after a `drop` the indexes are actually deleted

Comment: if it is reproducible 100% of the time - please share full actions sequence and postgres version. does not sound reproducible to me :/

Comment: @VaoTsun, I mean, I get this error all the time, but the database that I am dropping is a about 5GB in size, I can only reproduce it on my machine

Comment: oh... well - you probably need attention alive then.

Comment: Could you show us *exactly* how you're dropping this table? Do any other tables refer to `account`? And what version of Postgres is this? Finally, are you *really really really* sure there isn't a duplicate in your data? `select account_id from account group by account_id having count(account_id) > 1`

Comment: Please also show us how you're reloading the table, that can be relevant. If you're [building indexes concurrently](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY) that could lead to corruption.

Comment: @Schwern, thanks, I found the error, it is in my code. I pre-insert and account with ID=1 and when sequence uses it, I get this error of duplicate pkey. The second time sequence has value of 1 and no error occurs.

Comment: @Nulik so basically it was my first question which you said they are "impossible" ...

Comment: @KamilG.I was just fooled out by the fact that `reindexdb` fixed the error, but it didn't, only the first INSERT fails.